# How can I write below code in better way to keep looping endlessly?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, oop

This is my first time on Stackoverflow so please bear with me if my question is not clear !. I am trying to fetch all rows from tblproperty and loop through the array to convert it into an associative array. Once the property is fetched i am checking if the property is of the page or object. If the property if of the page we add the same in the propertiesArray. If the property is of object I am checking if the object is of the page or child of another parent object. The code below works for 3 levels (meaning Parent > Child > Child > Child). However I need to improve it to loop continuously if the object is of another parent object. Need advice how can I improve it. Further below code is in PHP on Server Side. I am looking to take it to Client Side. Any way to do it in Angular JS. Thanks in advance to all who chose to help !

$DBObj->querySelect("*","tblproperty","pgnid = $pageNID and propisactive = 1");

```
if($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() >= 1){
    $queryRecords = $DBObj->fetchAllRecordsArray();
    $rows = $DBObj->fetchNumOfRows();
    
    for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        //Properties of Objects are Loaded to Object Properties Array
        
        switch ($queryRecords[$i]['propof']){
            case "page":{
                if(array_key_exists($queryRecords[$i]['propofid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                    $propertiesArray[$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']] = [];
                array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto']));                                        
                break;
            }
                
            case "object":{
                $DBObj->querySelect("*","tblobject","pgnid = $pageNID and objisactive = 1 and objnid = ".$queryRecords[$i]['propofnid']);
                $queryRecord = ($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1)?$DBObj->fetchRecordArray():"";
                
                if($queryRecord != "")
                    switch($queryRecord['objof']){
                        case "object":{
                            $DBObj->querySelect("*","tblobject","pgnid = $pageNID and objisactive = 1 and objnid = ".$queryRecord['objofnid']);
                            $queryRecord1 = ($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1)?$DBObj->fetchRecordArray():"";

                            if($queryRecord1 != "")
                                switch($queryRecord1['objof']){
                                    case "object":{
                                        $DBObj->querySelect("*","tblobject","pgnid = $pageNID and objisactive = 1 and objnid = ".$queryRecord1['objofnid']);
                                        $queryRecord2 = ($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1)?$DBObj->fetchRecordArray():"";
                                        
                                        if($queryRecord2 != "")
                                            switch($queryRecord2['objof']){
                                                case "object":{
                                                    if(array_key_exists($queryRecord2['objofid'].$queryRecord1['objofid'].$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                                                        $propertiesArray[$queryRecord2['objofid'].$queryRecord1['objofid'].$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']] = [];
                                                    array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecord2['objofid'].$queryRecord1['objofid'].$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto']));
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    
                                                case "page":{
                                                    if(array_key_exists($queryRecord1['objofid'].$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                                                        $propertiesArray[$queryRecord1['objofid'].$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']] = [];
                                                    array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecord1['objofid'].$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto'])); 
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    case "page":{
                                        if(array_key_exists($queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                                            $propertiesArray[$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']] = [];
                                        array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecord['objofid'].$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto']));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            break;
                        }

                        case "page":{
                            if(array_key_exists($queryRecords[$i]['propofid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                                $propertiesArray[$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']] = [];
                            array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecords[$i]['propofid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto']));                            
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                break;
            }
                
            case "element":{                    
                $DBObj->querySelect("*","tblelement","pgnid = $pageNID and elisactive = 1 and elnid = ".$queryRecords[$i]['propofnid']);
                $queryRecord = ($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1)?$DBObj->fetchRecordArray():"";  
                
                if($queryRecord != ""){
                    $DBObj->querySelect("*","tblobject","pgnid = $pageNID and objisactive = 1 and objnid = ".$queryRecord['elofnid']);
                    $queryRecord1 = ($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1)?$DBObj->fetchRecordArray():"";
                
                    if($queryRecord1 != "")
                        switch($queryRecord1['objof']){
                            case "object":{
                                $DBObj->querySelect("*","tblobject","pgnid = $pageNID and objisactive = 1 and objnid = ".$queryRecord1['objofnid']);
                                $queryRecord2 = ($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1)?$DBObj->fetchRecordArray():"";
                                
                                if($queryRecord2 != ""){
                                    switch($queryRecord2['objof']){
                                        case "object":{
                                            $DBObj->querySelect("*","tblobject","pgnid = $pageNID and objisactive = 1 and objnid = ".$queryRecord2['objofnid']);
                                            $queryRecord3 = ($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1)?$DBObj->fetchRecordArray():"";
                                            
                                            if($queryRecord3 != ""){
                                                switch($queryRecord3['objof']){
                                                    case "object":{
                                                        
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                        
                                                    case "page":{
                                                        if(array_key_exists($queryRecord3['objid'].$queryRecord2['objid'].$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                                                            $propertiesArray[$queryRecord3['objid'].$queryRecord2['objid'].$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid']] = [];
                                                        array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecord3['objid'].$queryRecord2['objid'].$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto']));
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        }
                                            
                                        case "page":{
                                            if(array_key_exists($queryRecord2['objid'].$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                                                $propertiesArray[$queryRecord2['objid'].$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid']] = [];
                                            array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecord2['objid'].$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto']));
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }                                    
                                }                                                                
                                break;
                            }

                            case "page":{
                                if(array_key_exists($queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid'],$propertiesArray) != 1)
                                    $propertiesArray[$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid']] = [];
                                array_push($propertiesArray[$queryRecord1['objid'].$queryRecord['elid']],array($queryRecords[$i]['propid'] => $queryRecords[$i]['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $queryRecords[$i]['proplinkedto']));                            
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate your object recursively you need ... *recursion*

Create separate function with conditions inside.

- If current item belongs to page - push to array and return
- If current item belongs to object - take child element and repeat this check again.

*This is pseudo code, adjust how you need it*:

```php
if($DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() >= 1){
    $queryRecords = $DBObj->fetchAllRecordsArray();
    $rows = $DBObj->fetchNumOfRows();
    
    for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        recursiveAction($queryRecords[$i]);
    }
}

function recursiveAction(&$item, $propertiesArray) {
    switch ($item['propof']) {
        case 'page':
            // No need for that "if" check
            $propertiesArray[$item['propofid']][] = [$item['propid'] => $item['propvalue'],'proplinkedto' => $item['proplinkedto']];

            break;
        case 'object':
            $DBObj->querySelect(...);
            $queryRecord = $DBObj->fetchNumOfRows() == 1 ? $DBObj->fetchRecordArray() : "";

            if (!empty($queryRecord)) {
                // Here we convert common part of "object" into recursion
                recursiveAction($queryRecord);
            }

            break;
      case 'element':
            ...
    }
}
```